Can a window AC run at a 20 degree forward tilt?
I want to install a 5K window unit on my sailboat to blow thru a 13x19" top hatch.  Because of the deck layout, it sits at a 20 degree FORWARD angle. Would running it this way damage the unit? (I have solved the condensation, water proofing, insulation issues & baffled the 2 airflow, & a short test run shows good results).

More a problem that the salt air will destroy it in months, that condenser is aluminum!  Of course at $169 who cares right? LOL

The instructions should say what angles it works with.  I would imagine the problem would be condescension drains.  If they are at the back of the unit, they expect level or slight slope back.

Thanks for responding.  I've had one in the cockpit for decades and the aluminum tends to hold up pretty well.  And, the water has found it's way out of the left front edge of the bottom which sits just outside the hatch so I'm good there.  It may be less efficient not having the water to splash up onto the coils but it is cooling at about 20 degrees cooler than the air.  Thanks again.

The inexpensive compressor in a typical home AC will not run for long when inverted or tipped 90 deg on its side, as the parts will not be properly lubricated. But judging from the innards I've seen, tilting only 20 deg will still leave the bearings immersed in the lubricant.
I haven't looked inside any window ACs newer then three years so things may have changed. Still, I'm confident that any life reduction caused by tilting the compressor 20 deg out of vertical will pale in comparison to the life reduction caused (as Harper indicates) by installing cheap landlubber equipment in a marine environment.
The only surprise you're likely to encounter is thinking you've got the condensation drain problem solved when you really haven't. OTOH who has ever seen a sailboat without water dripping somewhere.

Or as non boat people/wives say, a boat is a hole in the water you pour money in.

Of course the main issue is the drain for the condensate. If you have that figured out, you are a step closer. Freon in any AC system is sealed and will work at any angle, so that is not an issue.
However the oil in the system for the compressor parts may pool where it shouldn't.
A call to the tech dept. of the manufacturer will give you the answer.

Thanks for your suggestion.
